# Reference request on operators with compact powers

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory, compact-operators

In this [Wikipedia page about compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators)
 at the very bottom it says:"If $B$ is an operator on a Banach space X such that $B^n$ is compact for some $n$, then the theorem proven above also holds for $B$."

I tried to find textbook or lecture notes to study such operators. But couldn't. Can someone help me to find a good reference?
Thank you.

Comment: They are known as power compact or quasi-compact operators, and covered in the first volume of Dunford-Schwarz Linear Operators, p.579-80, from where even the Wikipedia's wording is lifted.

Comment: @Conifold thank you for the useful information!